# problems with GUI input and output

Tags: java, swing, split, jtextfield

I have a project that will accept varying number of inputs and display varying number outputs. I need to implement using dynamic GUI. I have implemented some codes as below:

```
package orderMatcher2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class OrderMatcher2 {
    public static Scanner input;
    public static String order;
    public static List<String> sellOrder = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> buyOrder = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<Integer> sellVolume = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    public static List<Integer> sellPrice = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    public static List<Integer> buyVolume = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    public static List<Integer> buyPrice = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    public static int tempDiff;
    public static int sellTemp;
    public static int buyTemp;
    public static int priceSell;
    public static int priceBuy;
    public static JTextArea incoming;
    public static JTextField outgoing;

    public OrderMatcher2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Enter 'Exit or EXIT or exit' to end");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        incoming = new JTextArea(15, 50);
        incoming.setLineWrap(true);
        incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        incoming.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
        qScroller
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        qScroller
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        outgoing = new JTextField(20);
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                do {
                    System.out.println("> " + outgoing.getText());
                    order = outgoing.getText().trim();
                    // order = input.nextLine();
                    order = order.toUpperCase();

                    System.out.println("read " + order);
                    incoming.append(order + "\n");

                    if (order.equals("EXIT"))
                        System.exit(0);

                    if (!(order.equals("PRINT"))) {
                        System.out.println(order);
                        incoming.append(order);
                        orderOperationValidation(order);
                    }
                    if (order.substring(0, 4).equals("SELL")) {
                        orderOperationSell(order);
                    }
                    if (order.substring(0, 3).equals("BUY")) {
                        orderOperationBuy(order);
                    }

                    if (order.contains("PRINT")) {
                        callPrint();
                    }

                    /*
                     * if (order.equals("PRINT")) callPrint();
                     */

                    outgoing.setText("");
                    outgoing.requestFocus();

                } while ((order.contains("SELL")) || (order.contains("BUY"))
                        || (order.contains("PRINT")));

            }
        });

        mainPanel.add(qScroller);
        mainPanel.add(outgoing);
        mainPanel.add(sendButton);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(450, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void orderOperationValidation(String valid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] tokens = valid.split("[\\s@]", 0);
        for (String string : tokens) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

        if ((Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) < 0)
                || (Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) < 0)) {
            // System.out.println("Invalid Request");
            incoming.append("Invalid Request");
            new OrderMatcher2();
            OrderMatcher2.main(new String[0]);
        }
    }

    public static void orderOperationSell(String selling) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sellOrder.add(selling);
        String[] tempSell = selling.split("[\\s@]", 0);
        sellVolume.addAll(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer
                .parseInt(tempSell[1]))));
        sellPrice.addAll(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer
                .parseInt(tempSell[2]))));
        for (int i = 0; i < buyPrice.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sellPrice.size(); j++) {
                if (buyPrice.get(i) >= sellPrice.get(j)) {
                    tempDiff = buyVolume.get(i) - sellVolume.get(j);
                    if (tempDiff > 0) {
                        sellTemp = sellVolume.get(j);
                        priceSell = sellPrice.get(j);
                        System.out.println("TRADE  " + sellTemp + "@"
                                + priceSell);
                        incoming.append("TRADE  " + sellTemp + "@" + priceSell);
                    } else {
                        buyTemp = buyVolume.get(i);
                        priceSell = sellPrice.get(j);
                        System.out.println("TRADE  " + buyTemp + "@"
                                + priceSell);
                        incoming.append("TRADE  " + buyTemp + "@" + priceSell);
                    }
                    if (tempDiff > 0)
                        buyVolume.set(i, tempDiff);

                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void orderOperationBuy(String buying) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        buyOrder.add(buying);
        String[] tempBuy = buying.split("[\\s@]", 0);

        buyVolume.addAll(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer
                .parseInt(tempBuy[1]))));
        buyPrice.addAll(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer
                .parseInt(tempBuy[2]))));

        for (int i = 0; i < buyPrice.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sellPrice.size(); j++) {
                if (buyPrice.get(i) >= sellPrice.get(j)) {
                    tempDiff = buyVolume.get(i) - sellVolume.get(j);
                    if (tempDiff > 0) {
                        sellTemp = sellVolume.get(j);
                        priceSell = sellPrice.get(j);
                        System.out.println("TRADE  " + sellTemp + "@"
                                + priceSell);
                        incoming.append("TRADE  " + sellTemp + "@" + priceSell);
                    } else {
                        buyTemp = buyVolume.get(i);
                        priceSell = sellPrice.get(j);
                        System.out.println("TRADE  " + buyTemp + "@"
                                + priceSell);
                        incoming.append("TRADE  " + buyTemp + "@" + priceSell);
                    }
                    if (tempDiff > 0)
                        buyVolume.set(i, tempDiff);

                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void callPrint() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("  PRINT ");
        for (int i = 0; i < buyVolume.size(); i++) {
            if (buyVolume.get(i) != 0) {
                if (i <= 0) {
                    incoming.append("----  BUY  ----");
                    System.out.println("----  BUY  ----");
                }
                buyTemp = buyVolume.get(i);
                priceBuy = buyPrice.get(i);
                System.out
                        .println("BUY  " + Math.abs(buyTemp) + "@" + priceBuy);
                incoming.append("BUY  " + Math.abs(buyTemp) + "@" + priceBuy);
            } else {
                System.out.println("----  BUY  ----");
                incoming.append("----  BUY  ----");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < sellVolume.size(); j++) {
            if (j <= 0) {
                incoming.append("----  SELL  ----");
                System.out.println("----  SELL  ----");
            }
            if (sellVolume.get(j) != 0) {
                sellTemp = sellVolume.get(j);
                priceSell = sellPrice.get(j);
                incoming.append("SELL  " + Math.abs(sellTemp) + "@" + priceSell);
                System.out.println("SELL  " + Math.abs(sellTemp) + "@"
                        + priceSell);
            } else {
                incoming.append("----  SELL  ----");
                System.out.println("----  SELL  ----");
            }
        }

        if ((buyVolume.size() == 0) && (sellVolume.size() == 0)) {
            incoming.append("----  SELL  ----");
            System.out.println("----  SELL  ----");
            incoming.append("");
            System.out.println();
            incoming.append("----  BUY  ----");
            System.out.println("----  BUY  ----");
        }
    }

}
```

### The following errors .....

> sell 100@10
>   read SELL 100@10
>   SELL 100@10
>   SELL
>   100
>   10
>
> read

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at orderMatcher2.OrderMatcher2.orderOperationValidation(OrderMatcher2.java:122)
    at orderMatcher2.OrderMatcher2$1.actionPerformed(OrderMatcher2.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I guess this is your line number 122, `Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])`, make sure that tokens array is populated or apply some length check.

Comment: If you get an exception thrown you need to look at which line it is thrown at and try to figure out why. if you can't, you should tell us which line it is because we don't have your line numbering. In this case an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you should use a debugger and see why the array is accessed in a way it shouldn't.

Comment: You must be entering something less as input for `parseInt(token [ 1/2 ]`. Do check the input, if it's length is greater than `2`, only then  to perform this thingy, else restrain

Comment: Thanks .....I did remove the do loop ...and i worked

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the input of orderOperationValidation is not empty then split it. If you debug your code you will see at some point you passing an empty string to orderOperationValidation, and this if ((Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) < 0)
|| (Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) < 0) will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException becase the tokens doesn't have 2 or 3 items.